# can a delete from the android file system fail?

Tags: android

I am creating a file with:

```
OutputStream oStream = new OutputStream(openFileOutput("myFile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE));
```

At a certain point in the processing i want to delete it and raise an alarm if the delete fails.

the question is, *can* the delete fail?

I know the above will create:

```
/data/data/my.app/files/myFile.txt
```

AFAIK, this is private app storage that no longer exists on the sdcard.  its basically RAM.

Is it realistic to code against the chance i cannot delete a file from RAM?

Assuming an unrooted and properly operating phone could the delete of

```
/data/data/my.app/files/myFile.txt
```

ever fail?

IF the delete can fail, then what?  Tell the user to go to Settings | Applications | My App | Clear Data?  Tell them that their for is terribly broken and to get a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AFAIK, this is private app storage that no longer exists on the sdcard.

[Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) has never been [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Few devices have an "sdcard", either because they lack a card slot or because there is no card in the slot.

> its basically RAM.

No.

> Is it realistic to code against the chance i cannot delete a file

Something else in your app could have the file open. If you elected to have your app use multiple processes, one process could want to delete the file while the other process has the file open and locked.

If you are sure that none of these sorts of things is possible in your app, there is no realistic scenario that I can think of where a delete would fail. The closest thing would be due to a corrupt filesystem, in which case the user has much bigger problems.

Comment: if its not physical storage like an sdcard and its not temporary storage like RAM then what is it?

Comment: @user1126515: I have no idea what "physical storage" means in this context. [Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) is on-board flash memory. [External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), on modern Android devices, usually is part of the same on-board flash memory.

Comment: @user1126515: "the storage accessed by the code i posted" -- Android developers would refer to that as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and it is implemented as on-board flash memory. It is no more or less "physical" than is an SD card, or a USB thumb drive, or a hard disk, or a floppy disk, or a cassette tape.